# Does Ubiquiti UniFi have any form of PineApple Defense?

Tags: security, wifi, ubiquiti, unifi

Have an ongoing problem with WiFi RDP clients being disconnected while stationary and much more often when roaming.  The experience is much like being hacked or denial-of-service.  The PineApple took those WiFi hacking attempts and made them easy and cheap.

The Ubiquiti UniFi "Rogue Access Point" report claims there are rogue access points using our SSID.  These are not just known and unknown neighbouring access points, but APs using our same WiFi SSID names.  The UniFi software does not provide a list of all legitimate MAC addresses associated with all the SSIDs in use.  Each access point has several different MAC addresses - the physical ethernet ports plus one MAC for each SSID hosted on the AP.  The same SSID on another AP would have a different MAC.  The bottom line is that a simple WiFi installation may easily have 100 different electronic serial numbers and UniFi does not provide a view of all of them.

There are various reasons in our case that i do not believe there is actually a hacking attempt using a hidden malicious PineApple or compromised TabletPC with malicious WiFi code:
 1. When i power off all the APs, all the wLans / SSIDs disappear. Yes, the PineApple could certainly be smart enough to stop rebroadcasting as soon as the legitimate access points disappear, but i doubt it.  I would be more convinced if UniFi provided the list of all the legitimate MAC addresses.
 2. Disconnects occur for our TabletPCs with WiFi client certificates that only connect via certificates.  Yes, i heard there is a way around this as well.  Not sure what that entails, but would think that would take much more work like compromising a CA.
 3. At night when the building is less occupied, the same RDP session will stay up while roaming or stationary.
 4. There are so many other possible reasons for these TCP disconnects, but want to focus this question on the mechanism that UniFi uses to determine a rogue and if it does anything in response to detecting a rogue.

If the UniFi detected rogue access points by communicating over a backchannel hardware vLan only the list of legitimate MAC addresses and then a way to poke each of the broadcasting SSIDs for legitimacy from another AP, then it could have some form of PineApple detection and then defense (in some cases) by disconnecting the detected malicious AP.  It would explain why our RDP clients lose connection.

Comment: What about changing the SSID or creating an Alias and have some problematic clients connect to the Alias?

Comment: @Matt, this occurs for three different SSIDs - a radius authenticated, and two WPA2 networks.  Different clients connect to different SSIDs already.

Answer (score 0):

Ubiquiti says it is working on improving rogue detection, but makes no mention of doing anything when one is found.  Further, there is no way in the management interface to see all legitimate MAC addresses, so one must pssh into each AP and run a script to collect all layer two addresses.
[Re: 5.3.3. detects false rogue](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi-Wireless-Beta/5-3-3-detects-false-rogue/m-p/1755473/highlight/false)